# How can i delete space between two elements on website?

Tags: css

I have two division that I would like to clear space between them. How can I do it? You have code of this divisions in codepen link. Also added pure code here.

https://ibb.co/VqpwYzt - here is the gap I would like to clear, :

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}


/*treść*/

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 30px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#post {
  clear: both;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

#post .meta {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#post .entry {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}


/*boczny panel*/

#sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

#sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sidebar h2 {
  height: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar ul img {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="page">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="col-md-9" id="post">
      <h2 class="title">Patronat honorowy – Dziekan Wydziału Historyczno-Socjologiczny UwB</h2>
      <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 05.03.2019</p>
      <div class="entry">
        <p> Chcielibyśmy powiadomić, że pani dziekan, dr hab. Joanna Sadowska, prof. UwB, zgodziła się objąć patronatem honorowy niniejszą konferencją naukową. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="post">
      <h2 class="title">Patronat honorowy – Wojewoda Podlaski</h2>
      <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 05.03.2019</p>
      <div class="entry">
        <p> Jest nam również niezmiernie miło zdradzić, że do patronów honorowych niniejszej konferencji naukowej dołączył Wojewoda Podlaski, pan Bohdan Paszkowski. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="post">
      <h2 class="title">Patronat medialny – Radio Białystok</h2>
      <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 23.02.2019</p>
      <div class="entry">
        <p>Z przyjemnością możemy oznajmić, iż lokalna rozgłośnia radiowa, Radio Białystok, obejmie patronatem medialnym organizowaną przez nas konferencję.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="post">
      <h2 class="title">Patron wydarzenia</h2>
      <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 23.02.2019</p>
      <div class="entry">
        <p> Jest nam niezmiernie miło oznajmić, iż patronatem honorowym nad organizowanym przez nas wydarzeniem, zgodził się objąć Jego Magnificencja prof. dr hab. Robert W. Ciborowski. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--boczny panel-->
  <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Nasi partnerzy:</h2>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://www.uwb.edu.pl/pliki/logo/CMYK/w_uwb_kolor.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/img5.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/img6.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/img7.png" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Edit2: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzNVjV -

The first element is something like a posts on the left side and the second is a sidebar with patrons logo. First element start with content and the second called sidebar.

Comment: In the codepen seems to be working just fine...

Comment: Than why its displayed different on website, might be becouse of bootstrap ?

Comment: @Buszek Like Miguel says, it work's perfectly fine on codepen. Try to comment ur bootstrap out and see if the result is still the same. What kind of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: use class `col-md-12` instead `col-md-9` so it fills the whole row ;)

Comment: Try changing the width of #sidebar to 20% & remove the margin-right.
I think with this you won't need the bootstrap classes either.

Comment: @afishintaiwan agreed, done so far, bootstrap is not needed anymore and is mostly coming in the way, at least for the layout part

Comment: Damn, without bootstrap it works even better. Thank you very much, but also i have a question. Bootstrap is no more worth to use ? It scale better without bootstrap, mostly for phone resolution ?

Comment: Can you stop posting and deleting the same question over and over? TIA!

Comment: Now when i got answer i can stop to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Bootstrap classes & resize the sidebar. Also remove the margin-right from the sidebar.

HTML

```
    <div id="page">
 <div id="content">
  <div id="post">
   <h2 class="title">Patronat honorowy – Dziekan Wydziału Historyczno-Socjologiczny UwB</h2>
   <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 05.03.2019</p>
   <div class="entry">
    <p> Chcielibyśmy powiadomić, że pani dziekan, dr hab. Joanna Sadowska, prof. UwB, zgodziła się objąć patronatem honorowy niniejszą konferencją naukową. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
   <h2 class="title">Patronat honorowy – Wojewoda Podlaski</h2>
   <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 05.03.2019</p>
   <div class="entry">
    <p> Jest nam również niezmiernie miło zdradzić, że do patronów honorowych niniejszej konferencji naukowej dołączył Wojewoda Podlaski, pan Bohdan Paszkowski. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
   <h2 class="title">Patronat medialny – Radio Białystok</h2>
   <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 23.02.2019</p>
   <div class="entry">
    <p>Z przyjemnością możemy oznajmić, iż lokalna rozgłośnia radiowa, Radio Białystok, obejmie patronatem medialnym organizowaną przez nas konferencję.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="post">
   <h2 class="title">Patron wydarzenia</h2>
   <p class="meta">Opublikowany dnia 23.02.2019</p>
   <div class="entry">
    <p> Jest nam niezmiernie miło oznajmić, iż patronatem honorowym nad organizowanym przez nas wydarzeniem, zgodził się objąć Jego Magnificencja prof. dr hab. Robert W. Ciborowski. </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--boczny panel-->
 <div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <h2>Nasi partnerzy:</h2>
   </li>
   <ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.uwb.edu.pl/pliki/logo/CMYK/w_uwb_kolor.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img5.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img6.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="images/img7.png" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#page {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}


/*treść*/

#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 20px 0 10px 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#post {
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

#post .meta {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#post .entry {
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}


/*boczny panel*/

#sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    height: 38px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

#sidebar ul img {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```